# ANSI C: Pass variables from (s)scanf to function call

Tags: c, function, call, scanf

My question is whether or not it is possible to directly pass the parsed stuff from (s)scanf to a function call. In other words whether I have to initialise the variables which I want to pass to the function (and read via scanf) or not.

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean.

Comment: I'm splitting a string into different 'variables' (artist, title, genre) and I need those to pass them into a function.

Comment: I meant a code-based example of what you'd like to be able to do.

Comment: When it's not possible, then nevermind, I'll just assign it to variables.

But seriously - why on earth am I getting -2??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sscanf` returns the number of successful conversions.  It does not return the converted values.

So, you wouldn't be passing in the newly converted data when passing the return value of `sscanf` directly into another function (if that is what you are asking).

Answer (score 1):

`sscanf`, as others said, won't return the values, so there's no "directly" passing them. You can, however, wrap it with something like this:

```
struct mydata* parse(char* string) {
    struct mydata* ret = (struct mydata*) malloc(sizeof(struct mydata));

    sscanf(string, /* load the structure with the data */);

    return ret;
}
```

You can call whatever functions you need around that.